# placeins in subsection not working as intended

Tags: placeins

I desperately search for an answer now, nothing helps.
I want a graphic and a tabular appear before another subsection.

I use the placeins package for that, and expanded it to also do it in subsections. but the figure and the table are placed at the end of the document, on different pages.

It's still not working. here is the whole file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Is9gyBBw8-fJo6Zag0SnIIaJ5kpWH718/view?usp=sharing

```
\usepackage{placeins}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\subsection\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\@fb@secFB\subsection
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection{Tables and Figures}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:frog}This is a figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Widgets & 42 \\
Gadgets & 13
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier

\subsection{Mathematics}
...

\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

[image: second last page]
[image: last page]

Comment: it would be easier to help if you provided a test example that showed the problem you can use `example-image` as that is available for tests and fill in the document class and anything else required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I see you mention apa6 in comments that class moves all floats to the end, or before the appendix if you ave an appendix

Comment: Thanks David, the floatsintext option in the apa6 document class fixed my issue. I'm new here, shall I close this case or something?

Comment: I think it's probably a duplicate, but in future please always make the code you post useable